# local network: how to change broadcast address (with GUI)

Tags: networking, configuration, ip-address

### Is there a way, to change the broadcast address for network config via GUI?

if I set my network config to **"auto"**, connection establishes with following information for IPv4:

- IP-Address: 192.168.0.5
- Broadcast-Address: 192.168.1.255
- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- Primary DNS: 192.168.1.1
- Secondary DNS: 192.168.0.1

If I set it to **"manual"** and fill out:

- IP-Address
- Subnet mask
- Gateway and
- DNS Server

...with the information from above *(exept IP address: 192.168.0.222)*, the connection **won't establish** and "Broadcast-Address" differs:

- Broadcast-Address: 192.168.**0**.255

*Aim:* I want to access my desktop ubuntu with my phone within the local network.
Therefore my pc needs a static IP and the broadcast address is wrong, right?

[image: network config for IPv4 - manual settings]

#### edit

@migrc: my ping output

```
breaker222@breaker222-ubuntu-studio:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.247 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.331 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.294 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.289 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.297 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.256 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.940 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 6999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.247/0.369/0.940/0.217 ms
```

---

#### edit 2

I've solved my problem, by creating a fix-ip-rule (ger: "feste IP Adresse") for my pc within my router options. To do so, I've entered the gateway IP "192.168.1.1" in my browsers address bar and navigated to the "Network > LAN" Menu, where I've found the Option - and all without the need of console usage :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something incorrect in your configuration (when it's set in auto). With the netmask and ip address you are using you should not be able to reach the ip 192.168.1.1 (gateway and primary dns), in fact you should not be able to reach any 192.168.1.x ip address. Try to ping to 192.168.1.1 and check if you have response.

PD:This should be a comment but I haven't enough reputation

Comment: thanks for your comment - see my Question edit for the terminal output. I think this is a response.

Comment: I see. I was wrong, sorry. You can also change network configuration without GUI (if it is a valid solution for you). Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine

Comment: I've solved it another way - but thanks again for your participation. That motivated me to keep on trying :)